# Get a div by two data attributes and by exclude data attributtes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have some divs like these:

```
<div id="1" data-effect-in="swing" data-effect-out="bounce"></div>
<div id="2" data-effect-in="swing"></div>
<div id="3" data-effect-out="swing"></div>
<div id="4" data-effect-out data-effect-in="swing"></div>
<div id="5" data-effect-in data-effect-out="fadeIn"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ec7w2v2o/)

I need to get using jQuery the divs that have data-effect-in AND data-effect-out and these attributes have values not empty.

**Added requirement**

I need too get the divs that have data-effect-out with value not empty and NOT have data-effect-in.

The id's is GUID (I don't know the id, is generated from database)

Thanks!!

Comment: I'll try to solve this when I arrive to my office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divs that have data-effect-in AND data-effect-out and these attributes have values not empty:

```
$("div[data-effect-in][data-effect-in!=''][data-effect-out][data-effect-out!='']")
// result: div#1
```

Divs that have data-effect-out with value not empty and NOT have data-effect-in:

```
$("div[data-effect-out][data-effect-out!='']:not([data-effect-in])")
// result: div#3
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daLkn4cr/).